# Check with .NET if Remote Desktop Services (RDS) / Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH) is installed on a Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, terminal, rds

I need to detect with .NET if Remote Desktop Session Host is installed in windows 2008 - 2019 as part of the prerequisite checker for our product. It is not possible to install some parts in execution mode on a RDS Server, so I have to tell the user, that he has to change into installation mode ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Windows Server 2008 onwards, you can check whether RDS role is installed or not with the following type of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // 14 is the identifier of the Remote Desktop Services role.
    HasServerFeatureById(14);
}

static bool HasServerFeatureById(UInt32 roleId)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementClass serviceClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_ServerFeature");
        foreach (ManagementObject feature in serviceClass.GetInstances())
        {
            if ((UInt32)feature["ID"] == roleId)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch (ManagementException)
    {
        // The most likely cause of this is that this is being called from an 
        // operating system that is not a server operating system.
    }

    return false;
}
```

Reference: [Detecting Whether the Remote Desktop Services Role Is Installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/detecting-whether-terminal-services-is-installed)

Comment: Do you also know, how to check with .NET, if the Windows server 2008 or higher with RDS role is installed is in installation or execution mode?